# How to add a new column to an existing sheet and name it?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have the worksheet below:

```
Empid  EmpName  Sal
1      david     100
2      jhon      200
3      steve     300
```

How can I insert a new column named "Loc"?

```
Empid  EmpName   Loc   Sal

1      david     uk    100
2      jhon      us    200
3      steve     nj    300
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use insert method from range, for example

```
Sub InsertColumn()
        Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("C1").Value = "Loc"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

For your question as asked

```
Columns(3).Insert
Range("c1:c4") = Application.Transpose(Array("Loc", "uk", "us", "nj"))
```

If you had a way of automatically looking up the data (ie matching uk against employer id) then you could do that in VBA