# Need to loop through multiple sheets in multiple files and add a column to each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS_Count As Integer

  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
  myExtension = "*.xls*"
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

      WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 4 To WS_Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Select
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            Set RngCol = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        End With
            LastRow = RngCol.Rows.Count
            Range("L1:L" & LastRow).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Next i

      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

      myFile = Dir

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some comments about what the problem is. Do you get some error message and at which line?

Comment: What is your question? Where does your code fail?

Comment: No errors, it just doesnt add the column to any of the workbooks. I don't know why...

Comment: Add what column? What do you mean by "add"?  And I'm going to bet it's related to your use of `.Select`/`.Activate`. It's [best to avoid using those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I can't see anywhere a statement that says "insert" or "add"..., the last part looks to me that you define the range where you want to add some values into ( `Range("L1:L" & LastRow).Value` ), but this wouldn't add any extra columns.....  Maybe add something like this [How to add a new column to an existing sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728436/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-an-existing-sheet).

Comment: Column L is currently blank, I'm using Range("L1:L" & LastRow).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name to make all the cells  equal the Workbook name.

Comment: beginner mistake. somehow SaveChanges:=True got changed to False in my file.  Works like a charm now.